# Coldfusion: checking value in class

Tags: java, coldfusion

I'm looking at this cf [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7880.html).

I'm wondering if there is a way to check the value of a class data member every time it's accessed. So when coldfusion hits the following line:

```
<cfset firstname=emp.firstname>
```

I'd like to do something like this in the java class:

```
if(this.firstname is null) 
{ //do something }
return this.firstname
```

I realize, of course, that I can do this when the class is initialized, but was curious if this approach was possible.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I don't know what the syntax would be to do this in the java class (if it's possible)

Comment: Why does emp have to be a java class?  Why can't you use a cfc?

Comment: I realize there are other ways to do this. I was more wondering "Can this be done" rather than "Should this be done" I could call a function prior to the cfset that performed the same task as well, I was curious if java (which I'm unfamiliar with) had an "onread" function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's theoretical as opposed to a specific problem.

Comment: In C# there is syntactic sugar for having a getter method fire whenever you access a property with accessors=true like you do in coldfusion. However, in C# you have to explicitly write out the getter method still to handle the null whereas ColdFusion will just do a default. However, no such thing exists in java and writing out formal getProperty()/setProperty() is more of a tradition.

Comment: *getProperty()/setProperty() is more of a tradition* ... The scenario described is one of the main reasons why: to provide encapsulation, so it is easier to incorporate additional logic if needed.  The way the example class is currently written, that is NOT possible. Frankly, it is a bit atypical in that it declares `FirstName` as a *public* field (which is akin to CF's `this` scope). Meaning any class can modify the value *directly*. Instead, make "firstName" `private` and allow access only through a `public` getter()/setter(), and place any additional logic inside those methods.